# Change colour of tkinter button created in a loop?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I have created a grid of buttons using the code below:

```
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        btn = Button(frame, command=button_click(x, y))
        btn.config(height=1, width=1)
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky='nsew')
```

and I want to write the function button_click to turn the button a different colour once it has been clicked but as I have created all the buttons in a loop I don't have a specific variable name for each button so I'm not sure how best to do it? I didn't want to write 100 lines of code just creating buttons.. I thought maybe I could do this by passing the coordinates of the button to the function and somehow using this info but I can't find a solution. Any suggestions on how to do this or an alternative approach I could take would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def button_click(btn):
    color = random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])
    btn.config(bg=color)
    print(btn)

window = tk.Tk()

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        btn = tk.Button(window)    
        btn.config(text=f'{x}{y}',height=1, width=1, command=lambda button=btn: button_click(button))
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky='nsew')

window.mainloop()
```

**Update: buttons on frame**

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def button_click(btn):
    color = random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'green'])
    btn.config(bg=color)
    print(btn)

window = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        btn = tk.Button(frame)    
        btn.config(text=f'{x}{y}',height=1, width=1, command=lambda button=btn: button_click(button))
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y, sticky='nsew')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: when i use this the click seems to only change the last button, i assume as this is the most recently assigned to the variable btn? but much closer to what I am looking for!

Comment: @aidakemind No, it changes the button clicked for me. pls check again

Comment: @aidakemind do you have color change when you click the button?

Comment: yes, but only the very last button..maybe to do with the fact I have the buttons on a frame for sizing

Comment: @aidakemind I can't tell unless you post your whole code.

Comment: @aidakemind does my code work fine for you?