# How to place buttons on a Tkinter grid created in a for loop?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like buttons to be created dependent upon how many items are in a list of users. However, with the current state of the code, the  buttons all go on top of one another.
Any idea how I can fix this?

```
for user in users:
  b1 = Button(root, text="Select" + user)
button_3.grid(row = 3, column = 3,columnspan=3, pady=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use place every button in the grid. So instead use this.

```
for user in range(len(users)):
  b1 = Button(root, text="Select" + users[user])
  b1.grid(row=user, column=0) # you may swap. according to your need

button_3.grid(row = 3, column = 3,columnspan=3, pady=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would also like the variable user to be changed to whichever button is pressed. Is that something that is possible? Sorry, I am new to coding!

Comment: @s18 Here refer my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65325062/change-colour-of-tkinter-button-created-in-a-loop/65325570#65325570

Answer (score 0):

If you use specific numbers then every button will be placed one over the other... so instead give them a variable

In this :
`button_3.grid(row = 3, column = 3,columnspan=3, pady=1)`

Instead of `row = 3` and `column = 3` use `row = a` and `column = b` and increment the values of a and b by 3 every time the loop runs

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the coordinates in the grid (x,y) then change the values according to your needs.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as msgbox


top = tk.Tk()
top.title("MsgBox Test")

users = [ "Alice","Aby", "Aly", "Aria", "Antonette", "Ashley" ]

x,y = 0, 0
for user in users:
    btn1 = tk.Button(top, text = user)

    if users.index(user) == 3:
        x = 0
        y = y + 1

    btn1.grid(row=x,column=y)
    x = x + 1

top.mainloop()
```

You can also do two loops and then breaking out of it when the item no longer exists.

If it's a small list, you can also manually specify the grid positions.

```
tk.Button(window,text="row 0 column 0").grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(window,text="row 0 column 1").grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Button(window,text="row 0 column 2").grid(row=0, column=5) #Here the column is set to 5, but it will still be placed in column=2. place
tk.Button(window,text="Row 1 Column 0").grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(window,text="row 1 column 1").grid(row=1, column=1)
```

from [this](https://python-commandments.org/tkinter-grid/#tkinter-grid) example